# How can I see the output from my Jar file?

Tags: java, netbeans

I make a jar. I wrote in `System.out.println("my output");` And when I run the app in netbeans I can see the outputs but When I compile my jar file I run the app on command line I cant see the outputs.
How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you executing the JAR file? Have you added the `Main-Class` header in your MANIFEST?

Comment: yes I added the main class in manifest file. if I double click it , it works but I want to see outputs

Comment: You didn't answer my first question. How are you executing it from command line?

Comment: Execute from command line?

Comment: Do you use the `jar` command?, or just double click the icon

Comment: @wazy in command line I use  `java -jar myapp.jar`

Answer (score 0):

`java - jar myapp.jar` it is working